# Paragraph numbering (implicit)

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I would like to do auto numbering of paragraphs, something like this:

[image]

There are other questions asked about auto numbering paragraphs. But I did not see any that would do this numbering with implicit paragraphs. E.g. when you put two subsequent newlines in the TeX source code, without explicit `\paragraph` or any other explicit command. So the source code would look like this:

```
We should, as the ancients put it, let our "consciousness be occupied".

The typical mystics (at the higher emotional stage) speak about the "constant prayer" intended to keep their contact with the superconscious (whatever name they give to it).
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the basic idea:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{parnum}
\newenvironment{numbered}
 {\everypar{\stepcounter{parnum}\textsuperscript{\theparnum}\ignorespaces}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{numbered}
We should, as the ancients put it, let our ``consciousness be occupied''.

The typical mystics (at the higher emotional stage) speak about the 
``constant prayer'' intended to keep their contact with the superconscious 
(whatever name they give to it).

We should, as the ancients put it, let our ``consciousness be occupied''.

The typical mystics (at the higher emotional stage) speak about the 
``constant prayer'' intended to keep their contact with the superconscious 
(whatever name they give to it).

We should, as the ancients put it, let our ``consciousness be occupied''.

The typical mystics (at the higher emotional stage) speak about the 
``constant prayer'' intended to keep their contact with the superconscious 
(whatever name they give to it).
\end{numbered}

\end{document}
```

but without more specifications about what should happen with lists, section titles and so on, it's difficult to say more.

[image]

Comment: I need to do this inside all subsections. But specifiying `\begin{numbered}` inside all subsections is fine with me. I just did not want to add commands for all paragraphs.